# "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed" when using pytest-asyncio to test FastAPI routes

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-asyncio

I received the error

> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

each time I try to make more than one async call inside my test. I already tried to use all other suggestions from other Stack Overflow posts to rewrite the `event_loop` fixture but nothing works. I wonder what I'm missing?

Run test command:

```
python -m pytest tests/ --asyncio-mode=auto
```

requirements.txt

```
pytest==7.1.2
pytest-asyncio==0.18.3
pytest-html==3.1.1
pytest-metadata==2.0.1
```

test.py

```
async def test_user(test_client_fast_api):
    assert 200 == 200

    # works fine
    request_first = test_client_fast_api.post("/first_route")

    # recieve RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
    request_second = test_client_fast_api.post("/second_route")
```

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture()
def event_loop():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 13):

Add a file `conftest.py` to the directory where the test script is placed.

And write the following code:

```
import pytest
from main import app
from httpx import AsyncClient

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def anyio_backend():
    return "asyncio"

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def client():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
        print("Client is ready")
        yield client
```

And then use those fixtures in your own test code. For example, this is the real test code for my own project. You can change it to your own.

```
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient

@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_run_not_exists_schedule(client: AsyncClient):
    response = await client.get("/schedule/list")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    schedules = response.json()["data"]["schedules"]
    schedules_exists = [i["id"] for i in schedules]
    not_exists_id = max(schedules_exists) + 1
    request_body = {"id": not_exists_id}
    response = await client.put("/schedule/run_cycle", data=request_body)
    assert response.status_code != 200  

@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_run_adfasdfw(client: AsyncClient):
    response = await client.get("/schedule/list")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    schedules = response.json()["data"]["schedules"]
    schedules_exists = [i["id"] for i in schedules]
    not_exists_id = max(schedules_exists) + 1
    request_body = {"id": not_exists_id}
    response = await client.put("/schedule/run_cycle", data=request_body)
    assert response.status_code != 200
```

Finally, run in the project's terminal

```
python -m pytest
```

If all goes well, it should be OK.

This may involve libraries that need to be installed.

```
pytest
httpx
```

Comment: In case this answer isn't enough, try including this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73019163/2745495. The combination of both answers worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is the event loop fixture and TestClient pattern that worked for me:

```py
from asyncio import get_event_loop
from unittest import TestCase

from async_asgi_testclient import TestClient

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def event_loop():
    loop = get_event_loop()
    yield loop

@pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_example_test_case(self):
        async with TestClient(app) as async_client:
            response = await async_client.get(
                "/api/v1/example",
                query_string={"example": "param"},
            )
        assert response.status_code == HTTP_200_OK
```

Refer to the relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2006#issuecomment-689611040

---

*Please note - I could NOT figure our how to use Class based tests. Neither `unittest.TestCase` or `asynctest.case.TestCase` would work for me. `pytest-asyncio` docs ([here](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/)) state that:*

> Test classes subclassing the standard unittest library are not supported, users are recommended to use unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase or an async framework such as asynctest.

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest `pytest-asyncio==0.23.2` the issue can be fixed with

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio(scope="session")
```

Note that following wjkw1's answer, one will see the deprecation notice

```
  Replacing the event_loop fixture with a custom implementation is deprecated
  and will lead to errors in the future.
  If you want to request an asyncio event loop with a scope other than function
  scope, use the "scope" argument to the asyncio mark when marking the tests.
  If you want to return different types of event loops, use the event_loop_policy
  fixture.
```