# AttributeError in pytest with asyncio after include code in fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, telethon

I need to test my telegram bot. To do this I need to create client user to ask my bot. I found [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library which can do it.  First I wrote a code example to ensure that authorisation and connection works and send test message to myself (imports omitted):

```
api_id = int(os.getenv("TELEGRAM_APP_ID"))
api_hash = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_APP_HASH")
session_str = os.getenv("TELETHON_SESSION")

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient(
        StringSession(session_str), api_id, api_hash,
        sequential_updates=True
    )
    await client.connect()
    async with client.conversation("@someuser") as conv:
        await conv.send_message('Hey, what is your name?')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

@someuser (me) successfully receives message. Okay, now I create a test with fixtures based on code above:

```
api_id = int(os.getenv("TELEGRAM_APP_ID"))
api_hash = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_APP_HASH")
session_str = os.getenv("TELETHON_SESSION")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def client():
    client = TelegramClient(
        StringSession(session_str), api_id, api_hash,
        sequential_updates=True
    )
    await client.connect()
    yield client
    await client.disconnect()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_start(client: TelegramClient):
    async with client.conversation("@someuser") as conv:
        await conv.send_message("Hey, what is your name?")
```

After running `pytest` received an error:

`AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'conversation'`

It seems `client` object returned from `client` fixture in "wrong" condition. Here is `print(dir(client))`:

```
['__aiter__', '__anext__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'aclose', 'ag_await', 'ag_code', 'ag_frame', 'ag_running', 'asend', 'athrow']
```

Where I loose "right" client object from generator in fixture?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `@pytest_asyncio.fixture` decorator in async fixtures according to documentation https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/#async-fixtures.

Like this:

```py
import pytest_asyncio

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="session")
async def client():
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

I would rather use `anyio` instead of `pytest-asyncio`

- `pip install anyio`

Try this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def anyio_backend():
    return "asyncio"

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def conv():
    client = TelegramClient(
        StringSession(session_str), api_id, api_hash,
        sequential_updates=True
    )
    await client.connect()
    async with client.conversation("@someuser") as conv:
        yield conv

@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_start(conv):
    await conv.send_message("Hey, what is your name?")
```

Comment: Wow, it works. Thank you! Could you please explain, is it mean that pytest-asyncio is not suitable for this task?  Is it something base understanding I should know as beginner developer, or its just peculiar properties/oddities pytest-asyncio plugin?

Comment: @Andrey I use `pytest-asyncio` at 2019-2021, but use `anyio` since this year. The reason is that we use `fastapi` for work and anyio is one of it's dependence.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Set `asyncio_mode` to `auto`—see [readthedocs](https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) and [concepts](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/blob/master/docs/source/concepts.rst)—in which case you can omit `@pytest.mark.asyncio` and use `@pytest.fixture` for fixtures, **OR**
2. Use `@pytest_asyncio.fixture` per [Filip Hanes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73019163/6421801)

Option 1 is the easy way, but option 2 is available for those who want to run some async tests using custom async libraries (such as `trio`).