# What causes error 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I'm writing pytest tests for my FastAPI async project. Tests causes error :

session.add(user)

AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'

conftest.py:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f'postgresql+asyncpg://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{DB}_test'

engine = asyncio.create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionTesting = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    expire_on_commit=False,
    class_=asyncio.AsyncSession
)


@pytest.fixture(name='session')
async def session_fixture() -> Generator[SessionTesting, None, None]:
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    async with SessionTesting(bind=engine.connect()) as session:
    yield session
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

test_auth.py:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_token(session: SessionTesting, create_user):
    # async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://test') as ac:
    user = User(
    first_name='fixture',
    last_name='fixture',
    username='fixture',
    password=await get_hash('fixture')
    )
    session.add(user)
    await session.commit()
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://localhost:8000') as ac:
    credentials = {
        'username': 'fixture',
        'password': 'fixture'
    }
    response = await ac.post('/token/get_token', data=credentials, headers={"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError in pytest with asyncio after include code in fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996818/attributeerror-in-pytest-with-asyncio-after-include-code-in-fixtures)

Comment: I tried this:

Set asyncio_mode to auto—see readthedocs and concepts—in which case you can omit pytest.mark.asyncio and use pytest.fixture for fixtures, OR

Error is the same

Comment: I tried to change pytest.fixture to this:

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(name="session")

tests/conftest.py:52: in session_fixture
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
AttributeError: 'AsyncEngine' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

Answer (score 2):

You are yielding `session` (which seems to also be a fixture defined somewhere above) inside `session_fixture`, but you are not passing it as an argument to `session_fixture`. That results in yielding `async generator` instead of session.

```
@pytest.fixture(name='session')
async def session_fixture():
    ...
```

should be

```
@pytest.fixture(name='session')
async def session_fixture(session):
    ...
```

and also

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_token(session: SessionTesting, create_user):
```

should be

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_token(session_fixture: SessionTesting, create_user):
```

Comment: I did everything with pytest_asyncio but anyway thank you